# How to use UpdateMany and query for each _id in Array of Obejcts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I update the document in MongoDB. My Obejct-array is something like

```
const arrObj = [{ _id: "1", name: "Bruce", age:20 }, {_id: "2", name : "John", age:30 }]
```

now i want to replace all entries in my document with the new arrObj. Where _id = 1 it should change name and age of arrObj[0] and _id = 2 > arrObj[1]

```
updateMany({_id: arrObj.$._id}, arrObj})....-
```

Or should i have to use updateOne in an forEach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this address [MongoDB updateMany Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67950903/mongodb-updatemany-command)

use this

```
Tbl.bulkWrite([
{ 
  updateOne : {
 "filter" : { "_id" : ""001"" },
 "update" : { $set : {'age': 25, 'salary': 35000} 
 } } },
{ 
  updateOne : {
 "filter" : { "_id" : ""002"" },
 "update" : { $set : {'age': 23, 'salary': 25000} 
} } },
])
```