# MongoDB updateMany Command

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have been trying to update my MongoDB tables by '_id' using updateMany. I couldn't find a way or command in MongoDB documentary the way I want to update. I use python to manipulate the data.

Here is my entries:

```
Tbl = {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "001"
    },
    "name": "Alisha",
    "age": 24,
    "userid": 378824346,
    "salary": 30000
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "002"
    },
    "name": "Lana",
    "age": 22,
    "userid": 378824347,
    "salary": 20000
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "003"
    },
    "name": "Ivan",
    "age": 26,
    "userid": 378824348,
    "salary": 40000
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "004"
    },
    "name": "Yuri",
    "age": 25,
    "userid": 378824349,
    "salary": 34000
}
```

I want to update three of the entries at once by using updateMany(). My attempt is as followed:

```
Tbl.updateMany({
    '_id': {
        '$in': ["001", 
                "002", 
                "003"]
    }
}, {
    '$set': [{'age': 25, 'salary': 35000}, 
             {'age': 23, 'salary': 25000}, 
             {'age': 27, 'salary': 45000}]
})
```

I would like to know if I am able to update many entries in MongoDB like this. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: this is bulk-update, it is not possible with single `updateMany()` query, you can use [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/).

Answer (score 1):

*UpdateMany* won't work for multiple set queries. It will only take one set query for multiple documents.
Either use a loop with **updateOne** query or if you want to do it in single query use bulkWrite
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

```
Tbl.bulkWrite([
    { 
      updateOne : {
     "filter" : { "_id" : ""001"" },
     "update" : { $set : {'age': 25, 'salary': 35000} 
     } } },
    { 
      updateOne : {
     "filter" : { "_id" : ""002"" },
     "update" : { $set : {'age': 23, 'salary': 25000} 
    } } },
])
```

Comment: What would the command be if I execute it in python3? Thank you.

Comment: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/bulk.html 
This might help

Answer (score 0):

Following is the correct command

```
Tbl.bulkWrite([pymongo.UpdateOne(
         { "name" : "Alisha" }, { "$set" : {'age': 25, 'salary': 35000}}), 
               pymongo.UpdateOne(
         { "name" : "Ivan" }, { "$set" : {'age': 23, 'salary': 25000}})])
```